# How to transform a time value into YYYY-MM-DD format in Java?

Tags: java, time

How can I transform a time value into YYYY-MM-DD format in Java?

```
long lastmodified = file.lastModified();
String lasmod =  /*TODO: Transform it to this format YYYY-MM-DD*/
```

Comment: yes, i edited the question. Año = Year in spanish

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:Sec.Millisecond format in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Something like:

```
Date lm = new Date(lastmodified);
String lasmod = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(lm);
```

See the javadoc for [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Just to state the obvious here, if you're doing this in the context of a long-lived object or in a loop, you probably want to construct the SimpleDateFormat object once and reuse it.

Comment: @nsayer i would also like to state here, if you are doing a long lived object which is also in multi thread environment, you better create a new SimpleDateFormat everytime as it is not thread safe

Comment: You could synchronize the use of the SDF object in a multi-threaded environment. You still don't need to create it every time.

Answer (score 4):

```
final Date modDate = new Date(lastmodified);
final SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
final String lasmod = f.format(modDate);
```

[SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
String lasmod = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date(lastmodified));
```

Look up the correct pattern you want for SimpleDateFormat... I may have included the wrong one from memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date d = new Date(lastmodified);
DateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String lasmod = form.format(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

long lastmodified = file.lastModified();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String lastmod =  format.format(new Date(lastmodified));
```