# How to get the current time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:Sec.Millisecond format in Java?

Tags: java, date

The code below gives me the current time. But it does not tell anything about milliseconds.

```
public static String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");//dd/MM/yyyy
    Date now = new Date();
    String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
    return strDate;
}
```

I have a date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (`2009-09-22 16:47:08`).

But I want to retrieve the current time in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MS` (`2009-09-22 16:47:08.128`, where `128` are the milliseconds).

`SimpleTextFormat` will work fine. Here the lowest unit of time is second, but how do I get millisecond as well?

Comment: When all else fails, read the [documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1227, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what benefit does using SimpleDateFormat bring over just:
dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")  ?

Comment: @NickG Where is this `toString(String format)` method? The `java.util.Date` doesn't seem to have it. Are you referring to the Joda Time API? But one possible benefit is reuse of the same formatter object. Another is you don't have to add an API - Date class is a standard Java library class.

Comment: In Java 8 you can use [DateTimeFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for the same purpose.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe, but the newer DateTimeFormatter is thread safe.

Comment: Using Java 8 datetime API: `LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))`

Comment: I found this one for Date `SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT)` but seems there is no template for Time and Date at the same time

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: VERY Important to note that it is NOT the same behavior as the regular Oracle Java library.  Oracle Java will show 3 digits for ".S", as it stands specifically for milliseconds.  Whereas Android ".S" stands for fractions of seconds.  With Oracle Java you can only use one "S" (and always shows 3 digits), but in Android you can use any number of "S" characters you require, one digit shown per "S".

Comment: The below answer (`public String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date());
}`) should have more upvotes than this one.  More people will want the string rather than just the `SimpleDateFormat` object.

Answer (score 256):

A Java one liner

```
public String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date());
}
```

in JDK8 style

```
public String getCurrentLocalDateTimeStamp() {
    return LocalDateTime.now()
       .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
}
```

Comment: LocalDateTime and DateTimeFormatter are thread-safe unlike SimpleDateFormat

Comment: @Maxple any case where SimpleDateFormat cause issues?

Comment: @gaurav here is your cookie: https://www.callicoder.com/java-simpledateformat-thread-safety-issues/

Comment: But both of the examples are thread safe or did I miss something?

Comment: yes, the examples are thread safe. A new SimpleDateFormat is created every time.

Comment: This answer should have more upvotes; most people want the result String like me rather than just the SimpleDateFormat object

Answer (score 120):

You only have to add the millisecond field in your date format string:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

The [API doc of SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) describes the format string in detail.

Answer (score 50):

try this:-

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

or

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 46):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
       .toString()
```

> 2016-05-06T23:24:25.694Z

```
ZonedDateTime
.now
( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
)
.format(  DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )
.replace( "T" , " " )
```

> 2016-05-06 19:24:25.694

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, we have the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. These new classes supplant the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Be aware that java.time is capable of [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution (9 decimal places in fraction of second), versus the [millisecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) resolution (3 decimal places) of both java.util.Date & Joda-Time. So when formatting to display only 3 decimal places, you could be hiding data.

If you want to eliminate any microseconds or nanoseconds from your data, truncate.

```
Instant instant2 = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS ) ;
```

The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by default when parsing/generating strings. A `Z` at the end is short for `Zulu`, and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with resolution of up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). [Capturing the current moment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) in Java 8 is limited to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), with a new implementation in Java 9 capturing up to nanoseconds depending on your computer’s hardware clock’s abilities.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now (); // Current date-time in UTC.
String output = instant.toString ();
```

> 2016-05-06T23:24:25.694Z

Replace the `T` in the middle with a space, and the `Z` with nothing, to get your desired output.

```
String output = instant.toString ().replace ( "T" , " " ).replace( "Z" , "" ; // Replace 'T', delete 'Z'. I recommend leaving the `Z` or any other such [offset-from-UTC][7] or [time zone][7] indicator to make the meaning clear, but your choice of course.
```

> 2016-05-06 23:24:25.694

As you don't care about including the offset or time zone, make a "local" date-time unrelated to any particular locality.

```
String output = LocalDateTime.now ( ).toString ().replace ( "T", " " );
```

## Joda-Time

The highly successful Joda-Time library was the inspiration for the java.time framework. Advisable to migrate to java.time when convenient.

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format includes milliseconds, and is the default for the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4 library.

```java
System.out.println( "Now: " + new DateTime ( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
Now: 2013-11-26T20:25:12.014Z
```

Also, you can ask for the milliseconds fraction-of-a-second as a number, if needed:

```java
int millisOfSecond = myDateTime.getMillisOfSecond ();
```

Answer (score 13):

I would use something like this:

```
String.format("%tF %<tT.%<tL", dateTime);
```

Variable `dateTime` could be any date and/or time value, see [JavaDoc for `Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: Yeah, but you have to use multiple copies of same argument, like this: `String.format("%tF %<tT.%<tL", dateTime, dateTime, dateTime);`

Comment: No, you do not. The character `<` indicates to use the previous argument and not the next one...

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way was to (prior to Java 8) use,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

But [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is not thread-safe. Neither [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). This will lead to leading to potential concurrency issues for users. And there are many problems in those existing designs. To overcome these now in Java 8 we have a separate package called [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). This [Java SE 8 Date and Time](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) document has a good overview about it.

So in Java 8 something like below will do the trick (to format the current date/time),

```
LocalDateTime.now()
   .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
```

And one thing to note is it was developed with the help of the popular third party library [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/),

> The project has been led jointly by the author of Joda-Time (Stephen Colebourne) and Oracle, under JSR 310, and will appear in the new Java SE 8 package java.time.

But now the `joda-time` is becoming deprecated and asked the users to migrate to new `java.time`.

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project

Anyway having said that,

If you have a [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instance you can use below to convert it to the new `java.time`,

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long longValue = calendar.getTimeInMillis();         

    LocalDateTime date =
            LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(longValue), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String formattedString = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));

    System.out.println(date.toString()); // 2018-03-06T15:56:53.634
    System.out.println(formattedString); // 2018-03-06 15:56:53.634
```

If you had a Date object,

```
    Date date = new Date();
    long longValue2 = date.getTime();

    LocalDateTime dateTime =
            LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(longValue2), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String formattedString = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));

    System.out.println(dateTime.toString()); // 2018-03-06T15:59:30.278
    System.out.println(formattedString);     // 2018-03-06 15:59:30.278
```

If you just had the epoch milliseconds,

```
LocalDateTime date =
        LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochLongValue), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: minimum API level is 26

Answer (score 9):

I have a simple example here to display date and time with Millisecond......

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class MyClass{

    public static void main(String[]args){
        LocalDateTime myObj = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter myFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        String forDate = myObj.format(myFormat);
        System.out.println("The Date and Time are: " + forDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but does it add insight over, say, [rsinha's 5-year-old comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java#comment82604221_1459683)?

Answer (score 4):

To complement the above answers, here is a small working example of a program that prints the current time and date, including milliseconds.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class test {
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date now = new Date();
        String strDate = sdf.format(now);
        System.out.println(strDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this to get your **current time** in specified format :

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 System.out.print(dateFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));  }
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Actually I was using this solution for Android App , but to use Java.time class in Android we need to have API set to at least 27.
Anyway thanks for sharing the information.

Comment: Nearly all of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project with virtually the same API. Further adapted to Android <26 in the *ThreeTenABP* project. So there is no reason to ever touch those bloody awful old date-time classes again.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

The question and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1459683/10819573) use `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` which was the correct thing to do in 2009. In Mar 2014, the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted by the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Since then, it is highly recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API.

#### Solution using `java.time`, the modern date-time API:

```
LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
             .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
```

**Some important points about this solution:**

1. Replace `ZoneId.systemDefault()` with the applicable `ZoneId` e.g. `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")`.
2. If the current date-time is required in the system's default timezone (`ZoneId`), you do not need to use [`LocalDateTime#now(ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-); instead, you can use [`LocalDateTime#now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--).
3. You can use `y` instead of `u` here but [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) `u` to `y`.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
        // Replace ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable ZoneId e.g.
        // ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        String formattedDateTimeStr = ldt.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(formattedDateTimeStr);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run in my system's timezone, Europe/London**:

```
2023-01-02 09:53:14.353
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/fBcRf7)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reference to this:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
```

above format is also useful.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Date/Date_Format/Format_date_in_yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS_format_in_Java.htm

Answer (score 1):

Ans:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
ZonedDateTime start = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
String startTimestamp = start.format(dateFormatter);
```

Answer (score 1):

java.text (prior to java 8)

```
public static ThreadLocal<DateFormat> dateFormat = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
    protected DateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    };
};

...
dateFormat.get().format(new Date());
```

java.time

```
public static DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

...
dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

The doc in Java 8 names it [fraction-of-second](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) , while in Java 6 was named [millisecond](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). This brought me to confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **DateTimeFormatter** class from **java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter** package to format the required pattern.

```
public static String getTimeStamp() {
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-HH-mm-ss.SSS");
    return LocalDateTime.now().format(dateTimeFormatter);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply get it in the format you want.

```
String date = String.valueOf(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", new java.util.Date()));
```