# Convert timestamp to string

Tags: java, string, timestamp, joptionpane

In java I need to display 'time of the program start'

It must be in `String`.

How do I get the current time, and then convert it to a `String`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:Sec.Millisecond format in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try this

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String string  = dateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(string);
```

you can create any format see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: cannot find symbol 'SimpleDateFormat', how do I fix this?
Fixed: import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; Thanks a lot!

Comment: imports are missing

 import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

Comment: add this ---->   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

Answer (score 0):

new Date().toString();

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/

Dateformatter can make it to any string you want