# Convert java.sql.timestamp from yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss to MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: java

Is there an easy way to convert a timestamp field which is of format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` to a String of format `MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss`.
I was able to do so using substr  but was wondering if there is a straighforward way of converting it.
Thanks!

Comment: do you think using `SimpleDateFormat` is not a straight forward way?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "timestamp field"? A column in a database table? An input field (e.g. `JTextField`) in your Swing application? A form element in your HTML page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java

Comment: Keep in mind, dates or timestamps does NOT have a format. So, your question should be: "How to get a `java.sql.Timestamp` in `MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss` format"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all... `Date` or `Timestamp` objects **have it's own format**, so you don't have to care how is stored, **you need to change the format in the moment you show it, but not when you store it**:

When you need to show/print it use `SimpleDateFormat` for example if you want to show `Timestamp` in own format (`MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss`) you must do like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println("My date formatted is: " + sdf.format(timestamp));
```

Comment: In my opinion... best answer, definitely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Example :

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date d = input.parse("your date string goes here");

SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(output.format(d));  // will return date as string in format MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String format(Date sourceDate) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(sourceDate));

    return dateTimeFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this using **[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)**:

```
DateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
String str= d.format(timestamp);
System.out.println(str);
```