# Parsing date using SimpleDateFormat to get Time

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat, datetime-format

I am working on an Android application in which I need to parse my date to get my time. I am getting parsing exception when I am using my below code.

Here is the code:

```
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM hh:mm:ss yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss");
    Date date;
    try {   //selectedDateTime = Fri Jan 15 09:30:44 GMT+04:00 2016
        date = parseFormat.parse(selectedDateTime+"");
        System.out.println(printFormat.format(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Jan 15 09:30:00 GMT+04:00 2016" (at offset 0)

Comment: What's the exact parsing exception you're receiving?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Jan 15 09:30:00 GMT+04:00 2016" (at offset 0) @LudwigS this is the exception which i am getting.

Comment: @oblivion i just need to extract my time from Fri Jan 15 09:30:44 GMT+04:00 2016 date. Thats why i am trying to parse it to get my time 09:30:00

Comment: are you taking it from calendar instance?

Comment: Actually i am making instance of calendar to put my required time.. At the end i am getting that about DateFormat with time, which i need to parse. Please help me out to extract my Time value.

Comment: [Try that one piece of code....](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1459683/2183890)

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

Your formatting is off, try this.

Answer (score 0):

update

```
    try {
        String dateTest = "Fri Jan 15 09:30:00 GMT+04:00 2016";

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        java.util.Date d = (java.util.Date) formatter.parse(dateTest);
        System.out.println("" + d);

        SimpleDateFormat print = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(print.format(d));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

output

```
Fri Jan 15 11:00:00 IST 2016
11:00:00
```

Following code can help you understand how exactly formatting syntax change for date formatting

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


    System.out.println("Date: \t"+calendar.getTimeInMillis());

    String dateAsText_ = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date(Long.parseLong(""+calendar.getTimeInMillis())));
    Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(""+calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
    System.out.println(""+dateAsText_);

    SimpleDateFormat ft =  new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    System.out.println(""+ft.format(date));

    SimpleDateFormat time_ft =  new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm aa");
    System.out.println(""+time_ft.format(date));
```

> Output

```
Date:   1452766759531
2016-01-14 15:49:19
14-Jan-2016
03:49 PM
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Strings are wrong. The correct ones are:

```
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your initial date format is wrong. Can you share the value of selectedDateTime.
I guess it in different format (as per your comment) like Fri Jan 15 09:30:44 GMT+04:00 2016

If so please try this code

```
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss");
Date date;
try {   //selectedDateTime = Fri Jan 15 09:30:44 GMT+04:00 2016
    date = parseFormat.parse(selectedDateTime+"");
    System.out.println(printFormat.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```