# Making a String Formatted for time

Tags: java

I am trying to format a string a certain way. Currently I have

```
String timeString = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec ;
```

however I have hour min and sec as integers and whenever they are a single digit i would like to add a placeholder 0 in front. How would I do that?

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java) did not answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to format your numbers like

```
String timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, min, sec);
```

Comment: Thank You! This was what I needed.