# parse String variable from database (type datetime) to LocalDateTime variable using Resultset

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc, resultset

I'm trying to convert a String value (initially a LocalDateTime variable) that was stored in a database (as datetime) and parse it into a LocalDateTime variable. I've tried it with a formatter:

```
String dTP;
dTP=(rs.getString("arrivedate"));
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
            LocalDateTime dateTimeParked = LocalDateTime.parse(dTP,formatter);
```

And without a formatter:

```
String dTP;
dTP=(rs.getString("arrivedate"));
LocalDateTime dateTimeParked = LocalDateTime.parse(dTP);
```

But I get the same error each time:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-07-09 01:30:00.0' could not be parsed at index 10
```

My thinking is that index 10 is the space between date and time.

Could anyone help me with this? I've been at it for hours :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a error in the format of the that causes the issue. Please refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html.The ISO date time is of the format  '2011-12-03T10:15:30' .  The following will give you the idea

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    String isoDate = "2016-07-09T01:30:00.0";
    //  ISO Local Date and Time '2011-12-03T10:15:30'
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
    LocalDateTime dateTimeParked = LocalDateTime.parse(isoDate, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTimeParked);




    String date = "2016-07-09 01:30:00.0";
    DateTimeFormatter formatterNew = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-LL-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    LocalDateTime dateTimeParkedNew = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatterNew);      
    System.out.println(dateTimeParkedNew);

}
```

This prints : 
2016-07-09T01:30
2016-07-09T01:30

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! It works great now. @Ramachandran G A

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, your string is in SQL format which differs from the canonical version of ISO 8601 format by using a space character in the middle rather than a `T`.   So either replace the space with a `T` or define a formatting pattern for parsing.

## Use smart objects, not dumb strings

But the bigger problem is that you are retrieving the date-time value from your database as a string. You should be retrieving date-time types of data as date-times types in Java.

For drivers compliant with JDBC 4.2 and later, you should be able to use `setObject` and `getObject` with java.time objects.

For SQL type of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` use `LocalDateTime`. For `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use `Instant` or perhaps `ZonedDateTime` depending on the database.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class );
```

Store in database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
```

I'm not sure about the millisecond part though (In case it is more than 1 character long).

Comment: This thread should help you further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java