# How to format datetime from sqlite in android and show on text view

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime, textview

To format date and time which get from sqLite like `2016-07-13 13:10:00`. I want to format it like `07-Jul-2016, 01:10 PM`.

I have tried lots of solution but I can't find any better format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some of the solutions you have tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you format date and time in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android)

Comment: I think its not a duplicate post. My post little bit difference.

Comment: They are different, should be `13-Jul-2016, 01:10 PM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  String strCurrentDate= "2016-07-13 13:10:00";
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  Date newDate = null;
  try {
      newDate = format.parse(strCurrentDate);
      format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
      String date = format.format(newDate);
      System.out.println(date);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: correction "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" in line 2

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

String inputDateStr="2011-01-11";
Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputDateStr);
String outputDateStr = outputFormat.format(date);
```

from `2011-01-11` to `11 Jan 2011`

refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

to find the pattern of the date from your sql and the new pattern you want

Comment: can I convert `11 Jan 2011` to `11-Jan-11` ?

Comment: yes use `"dd-MMM-yy"`

Comment: Is there any solution to do the same operation with time format? I have such stringl ike `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm` and I could change date format as above shown, but I can't not change the time format. How can I do? Thanks.