# Parsing Date Time with optional milliesconds

Tags: java, parsing, datetime

I'm trying, using java, to parse a given string to DateTime, given that the string is in the following format:
    YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[.s+]Z
The milliseconds are optional and can be any nubmer of numbers after the decimal point. 
How can it be done simply?

Comment: "and can be any nubmer of numbers after the decimal point" - do you really mean that? Does ".1" mean 100 milliseconds or 1 millisecond? What about ".3456"?

Comment: Had you tried? Please post your code.

Comment: If milliseconds  are optional than remove these from String before parsing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java

Comment: Do you need the milliseconds if they are present?

Comment: Sadly, I can't post my code online. First, I came to realize these aren't milliseconds. After the decimal point is 'sub-second', so .5 means half a second and not 5 milliseconds. Second, I would prefer not to remove these digits, since it will be considered as data lost in translation, and I try to minimize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OffsetDateTime.parse()` does this out of the box. Say we have:

```
    String[] input = {
            "2017-03-07T16:06:13+01:00",
            "2017-03-07T16:06:13.1+01:00",
            "2017-03-07T16:06:13.22+01:00",
            "2017-03-07T16:06:13.333+01:00",
            "2017-03-07T16:06:13.4444+01:00",
            "2017-03-07T16:06:13.55555+01:00",
            "2017-03-07T16:06:13.666666+01:00",
            "2017-03-07T16:06:13.7777777+01:00",
            "2017-03-07T16:06:13.88888888+01:00",
            "2017-03-07T16:06:13.999999999+01:00"
    };

    for (String ips : input) {
        OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.parse(ips);
        System.out.println(dt);
    }
```

This prints:

```
2017-03-07T16:06:13+01:00
2017-03-07T16:06:13.100+01:00
2017-03-07T16:06:13.220+01:00
2017-03-07T16:06:13.333+01:00
2017-03-07T16:06:13.444400+01:00
2017-03-07T16:06:13.555550+01:00
2017-03-07T16:06:13.666666+01:00
2017-03-07T16:06:13.777777700+01:00
2017-03-07T16:06:13.888888880+01:00
2017-03-07T16:06:13.999999999+01:00
```

As Andreas noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42651504/5772882), `OffsetDateTime.toString()` prints as many groups of three decimals as necessary for full accuracy. You may of course do you own formatting, but I consider this outside the question.

You do get a `DateTimeParseException` if you try to feed it 10 decimals (or more), though.

Comment: Dang, I didn't even try without using a formatter. Very nice. +1

Answer (score 2):

First, your format string is wrong. Year and day should be in lowercase, i.e. `yyyy` and `dd`, and the `T` is literal, so it should be quoted, i.e. `'T'`.

Assuming that by *"any number of numbers after the decimal point"* you're actually talking about between 0 and 9 digits, i.e. nanoseconds, the use of the word *"milliseconds"* is misleading. *Fractional seconds* would be the right way to say that.

To support varying number of fractional digits with Java 8 Time API, use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
        .appendOffset("+HH:mm", "+00:00")
        .toFormatter();
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-03-07T09:47:15+01:00", fmt));
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-03-07T09:47:15.123456789-02:00", fmt));
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-03-07T09:47:15.42000-05:30", fmt));
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-03-07T09:47:15.2468000-05:30", fmt));
```

*Output*

```
2017-03-07T09:47:15+01:00
2017-03-07T09:47:15.123456789-02:00
2017-03-07T09:47:15.420-05:30
2017-03-07T09:47:15.246800-05:30
```

As you can see, trailing zeroes are truncated in 3-block increments when the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) value is printed, i.e. when [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString--) is used to format the result.