# Correct DateFormat to parse this string?

Tags: java

When I use this code to parse a date String, the time is parsed incorrectly. This code prints `Wed Feb 14 15:06:06 EST 2018`. What date format should I use to parse this input?

```
String input = "2018-02-14 14:57:59.487927";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");

System.out.println(formatter.parse(input));
```

Comment: Your date displays millions of milliseconds, so the time is added to what's parsed. If you truncate the last 3 digits you'll get a date more similar to your desired outcome.

Comment: I dont work with java but a quick google showed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1459683/2647442) SO answer that shows the format being `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`. Which sounds similar to what Mena mentioned.

Comment: @Marie not really, that question is still working with milliseconds, here we're dealing with microseconds

Comment: @Mena can I specify the format so it parses the millions of milliseconds? I would htink this would work, but it gives the same result `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"`

Comment: @Mena Gotcha, nvm!

Comment: I think the date format should be like this : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'm using java 1.7, the answer mentions I can use `Timestamp` to resolve nanos, but I'm not clear how... should I extract the date using this `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and then parse the nanos to the timestamp?

Comment: @ab11 If you actually need microsecond precision, I'd suggest you get the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) of the Java 8 Time classes. --- Anyway, with `SimpleDateFormat`, the uppercase `S` represents *millisecond*, so anything other that exactly 3 of them, i.e. `SSS`, makes no sense at all, and you need to discard any extra fraction digits using `substring`, before parsing the input.

Answer (score 1):

So far with my testing the best apporach for this is using DateTimeFormatter that will math what you want.

```
String input = "2018-02-14 14:57:59.487927";
DateTimeFormatter r =DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
LocalDateTime a =LocalDateTime.parse(input,r);
System.out.println(a);
```

With this you will get

```
Hour: 14
Minite: 57
Second: 59
Nano: 487927000
```

And with SimpleDateFormat you will get milisecond always with 927 and so far you will always loose precision.

```
m   Minute in hour      Number  30
s   Second in minute    Number  55
S   Millisecond         Number  978
```

So far you best precission is only 3 digits and there is no nanoseconds in SimpleDateFormat.

I suggest to use the new Java 8 Date libraries.