# How to format a date to insert in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm coding a Java app to insert data in Elasticsearch 7.5.1. When creating the index the property was set like this:

```
"datetime":{
   "type":"date"            
}
```

Now when inserting the date I'm getting this error:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse field [datetime] of type [date] in document with id '195'. Preview of field's value: '2018-11-23 10:38:00'
```

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String v = dateFormat.format(date);
```

And checking a working index I can see it's formatted like this, example: `2019-10-09T11:11:38.879-04:00`

What is the mask to create that format?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use for example `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html), you can specify multiple date formats for your field "datetime".

The datetime from the error message above, `2018-11-23 10:38:00`, needs to be mapped with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in order to get indexed.

Please consider setting a timezone or even better use [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format as elastic internally stores all dates as UTC. If you don't provide a Timezone, the datetime you are indexing will be assumed as UTC but your application may run in a different Timezone. This can cause trouble ;)

Back to the solution. Define the mapping like this for the datetime field:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "datetime": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ||epoch_millis"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And it will process datetime values like

- `2018-11-23 10:38:00` (your current format)
- `2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700` (ISO 8601)
- `1095379198` ([unix time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))

If you want more background information on date & time handling in java, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java/1459683#1459683). Old, but gold.

Cheers!