# Spring Boot JPA Hibernate - Storing Date with millisecond precision

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

Spring Boot version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
Java 11
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE
runtime(mysql:mysql-connector-java)

Server DB MariaDB (ver. 10.5.5-MariaDB)
Java MariaDB Connector J:2.6.0[stable]

I'm trying to persist a java.sql.Timestamp object in Hibernate with millisecond precision. I need save dates to db with milliseconds. For example: 2020-10-08 03:23:38.454.

my domain:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "date_test")
public class DateTestDomain {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "date", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP(3)")
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar dateTest;
}
```

my repo:

```
@Repository
public interface DateTestRepo extends JpaRepository<DateTestDomain, Timestamp> {
}
```

save date to db:

```
private final JdbcTemplate db;
...
        long testTime = 1602120218454L;
        Timestamp dateTimeStamp = new Timestamp(testTime);
        db.update("INSERT INTO date_test" + " (date) VALUES( \"" + dateTimeStamp + "\")");
```

UPD: Result of sql is right as I need!!! This method working perfect:
2020-10-08 03:23:38.454

But with hibernate/JPA result is FALSE.
Debug Trace:
2020-10-09 22:26:53.120 Hibernate: insert into date_test (date) values (?)
2020-10-09 22:26:53.122 TRACE 95038 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2020-10-09 22:26:53.044]

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
        dateTestDomain.setDateTest(calendar);

        dateTestRepo.save(dateTestDomain);
```

Result of sql: the fractional seconds are always set to **.000** with hibernate sql insert:

> 2020-10-09 22:26:53.000

please help. I need save to db time with millisecond precision throw JPA.

UPD:

I try sql dialect:
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect than org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55InnoDBDialect than org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect than org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB105Dialect
without success.
UPD 1:
Hibernate: INSERT INTO date_test (timestamp, local_date_time, local_date_timea) VALUES (NOW(3), ?, ?)
2020-10-10 15:33:29.099 TRACE 44072 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2020-10-10 15:33:29.051]
2020-10-10 15:33:29.100 TRACE 44072 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1602336809051,areFieldsSet=true...

Result SQL:
2020-10-10 15:33:29.101, 2020-10-10 13:33:29.000, 2020-10-10 15:33:29.000.

And one more problem:
DB dates:
2020-10-10 16:19:42.578
2020-10-10 16:20:47.000
2020-10-10 16:20:47.888
2020-10-10 16:20:47.892
2020-10-10 16:20:47.896
2020-10-10 16:20:47.900
Hibernate: select datetestdo0_.timestamp as timestam1_0_ from date_test datetestdo0_ where datetestdo0_.timestamp>?
binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2020-10-10 16:20:47.893]
2020-10-10 16:20:47.888
2020-10-10 16:20:47.892
2020-10-10 16:20:47.896
2020-10-10 16:20:47.9

jdbcsql:
select timestamp from date_test where timestamp>"2020-10-10 16:20:47.893"
2020-10-10 16:20:47.896
2020-10-10 16:20:47.900

jpa/hibernate not working with milliseconds...

Comment: You can append to the sql a formatted string of the time with millisecond precision.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java

Comment: Formatted string?  I have Timestamp - timestamp formatted with milliseconds.

Comment: Replace .append(dateTimeStamp) with .append(YourFormattedString). You can find how to get a formatted string representing date and time in the link

Comment: @Dario  in this place - not is my problem. jdbctemplate working true, but in the last 3 row: my problem hibernate dateTestRepo.save(dateTestDomain) are always set to .000 timestamp. This is my problem. I, not need format the timestamp to string or change the sql query, i need that jpa save to db my timestamp with milliseconds same as jdbctemplate.

Comment: For starters you should be comparing equal things. What you are doing is passing a static SQL with the result of `Timestamp.toString` into the query. What you should have been doing is `db.update("INSERT INTO date_test (date) VALUES(?);", timestamps);` as that will use proper sql conversion which JPA/hibernate is also using. Finally add an `@Temporal(TIMESTAMP)` to your field definition.

Comment: @M. Deinum One more... I need in the db this date time format: 2020-10-08 03:23:38.454. I add annotation @Temporal(TIMESTAMP). but after save to db with JPA/Hibernate in db truncate milliseconds to .000.

Answer (score 1):

Since JPA 2.2 there is support of java8 date and time API. I have not tried if it will solve your problem or not but can you try with java8's `LocalDateTime` instead of `Calendar` type.

Replace:

```
@Id
@Column(nullable = false, name = "date", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
```

Comment: thank, but @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property.  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html

Comment: As i mentioned they are supporting other types as well since 2.2 version. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-java-time check this

Comment: with annotation Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property. Without - yes, are supporting other types. Please see your link one more. in point 5 nothing about annotation Temporal. But this not important for new hibernate, where changed to new annotation org.hibernate.annotations.Type( type = "calendar" ) . But all the same not working.

Comment: In that case can you try without @Temporal ?

Comment: im trying all what is can... its not working. and select from db same not working as must be.

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried locally and when I save to db I am getting second precision as you wanted. (i.e 2020-10-10 21:37:55.102). Even with your configuration of entity.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Try this one instead of using new Date()

Comment: thanks. if you see debug trace sql query, that its not problem in value. Value sending with milliseconds. After hibernate get the time truncate milliseconds and save without.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution but a work around, works perfectly:
Instead of storing the actual date, just store the `long` value of your date, by calling the `date.getTime()` method, store this result, when getting the date from the date use `new Date(longValue)`  to recreate your original date using the `longValue` stored in your database, this approach at least preserves your millisecond precision