# how to know the datetime contains minisecond in Java

Tags: java

Now I am parsing datetime from frontend like this:

```
public static Long stringToUnixTimestampMinisecend(String datetime) {
        Long resultDatetime = 0L;
        try {
            Date startLocalTime = DateUtils.parseDate(datetime, DATETIME_PATTERN);
            resultDatetime = startLocalTime.getTime();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error("parse error", e);
        }
        return resultDatetime;
    }
```

this is the DATETIME_PATTERN define:

```
 public final static String[] DATETIME_PATTERN = {
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            "yyyy-MM-dd",
    };
```

but now I want to know the frontend parameter is contain minisecond, if the format like this `2020-11-05 23:59:59`, then I could append `999` in the end of parsed date(default is `000`). what should I do to make this?

Comment: What is the reason of using `"yyyy-MM-dd"` ?

Comment: Is this Joda Time?

Comment: it is `org.apache.commons.lang3.time` @MCEmperor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:Sec.Millisecond format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java)

Comment: Switch to using the `java.time` classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern

```
  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",
```

If you want to add milliseconds at the end, I'll give you an example

```
Date date = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.999");
System.out.println("Date: " + sdfDate.format(date));
```

Comment: but the input from parameter is `2020-11-05 23:59:59`, I want to append 999 in the end of time. @borchvm